# Django call CBV form other place

Tags: django

hey guys I have a specific issue.
I have a view:

```
class Upload(CreateView):
    model = Banner
    fields = ["image"]
    success_url = '/url/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #some specifics operations...
```

This image are uploading to /upload

And in other place (e.g. /other_place, image in this dict are not uploading) I have a directory with other images. I get path to this images:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        l.append(file)
```

And in template:

```
{% for i in l %}
    <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}other_place/{i}}">
{%endfor%}
```

And I have nice template with all of this image. But now I need to upload selected image. specifically I need to call Upload view to upload selected image. Do you know what I mean? :D

Comment: No, not really. Are you asking how to upload an image that already exists on your server?